# How to calculate $\sum_{i= 0}^{k-1}\left \{ \frac{ai+b}{k} \right \}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How to calculate: $$F=\sum_{i= 0}^{k-1}\left \{ \frac{ai+b}{k} \right \}$$
where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and $(a,k)=1$; $\left \{ \frac{ai+b}{k} \right \} =$ fraction part of $\frac{ai+b}k$

Such problem so strange for me. Please help me solve it, give me solution or a hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(a,k)=1$, the numbers $ai$ and also the numbers $ai+b$ run through all residue classes modulo $k$ exactly once. Therefore, we can simplify
$$ F=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac ik=\frac1k\frac{k(k-1)}{2}=\frac{k-1}2.$$